# Laravel Many To Many Relationship getting data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, many-to-many

this is my campus model
i have stripped the models for readability
and of course there is join table named as campus_user with id, campus_id, user_id
users can subscribe to campuses
now i want 2 things
1. Get all the users subscribed to a specific campus
2. Check to see if a specific user ( say with id = 1 ) is subscribed to a specific campus ( say with id = 2 )

```
class Campus extends \Eloquent{
   protected $table = "campuses";

   public function users(){
      return $this->belongsToMany("User");
   }
}

// this is my user model

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

   use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
   protected $table = 'users';
   protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

   public function campuses(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('\Models\Campus');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the most "Eloquent like" way would be using relationship querying:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations

A simple example would be returning users with any campuses.

```
// Get users with any campus relationship.
$users = User::has('campuses')->get();
```

However you need something more powerful.

For 'users' in a specific 'campus'.

```
// Get 'users' in a 'campus' where the 'name' column equals 'foo'.
$campus = 'foo';

$users = User::whereHas('campuses', function($query) use ($campus) {
    $query->where('name', $campus);
})->get();
```

For a specific 'user' in a specific 'campus' the code would almost be the same.

```
// Find the 'user' with a primary key of '1' in the 'campus' where
// the 'name' column equals 'foo'.
$primaryKey = 1;
$campus = 'foo';

$users = User::whereHas('campuses', function($query) use ($campus) {
    $query->where('name', $campus);
})->find($primaryKey);
```

As you can see the last example replaced the `get()` method from the previous example.
You can do the same with the callback in the `whereHas()` method when you want to query using the primary key. This would result in the following.

```
...
$query->find($campus);
...
```

All the methods described above can be found in the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` class.

I would recommend taking a look at some of the source files to get a better understanding how request are handled.